# Getting error "cannot resolve findViewById(int)'

Tags: android, button, android-fragments

I have a main activity and when I press a button, i am navigated to a swipe Tab view. Now I want to have a Clickable Button in these tabs and present a toast when the button is pressed. Here is the code I use:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class laundry extends Fragment {
Button btn_service;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_laundry, container,false);
    btn_service = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_service);
    btn_service.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

But the findViewById is not a know symbol to this activity. Is there an alternative way to incorporate clickable buttons in fragment activity like above?

Ran the project and I get this error. ( I cant know if the suggested changes worked, my app crashed with the following error) This is a fragment activity and I am trying to generate a toast when a button is clicked.

```
public class in_room_dining extends Fragment
{
Button btn_order;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
 public void onClick(View v)
{
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_in_room_dining, container, false);
}
}
```

The error I got is :

```
11-29 10:57:42.820      938-938/com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION:     main
Process: com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax, PID: 938
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.appt.shreyabisht.staymax.in_room_dining.onCreateView(in_room_dining.java:23)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
```

(in_room_dining.java:23) is btn_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

Comment: all the 4 answer are correct. accept any one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class laundry extends Fragment {
Button btn_service;
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_laundry, container,
                false);

    btn_service = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_service);
    btn_service.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

         //your Code Goes Here    
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: for "btn_service.setOnClickListener(this);" it says setOnClickListener android.view.View.OnClickListener in view cannot be applied to this class

Comment: great. can you also tell me how to add toast to a button in such fragment activity. I dont need the button to do anything, just need a text saying button is pressed. thanks

Comment: I ran the code ( updated my question with that ) and I got NullPOinterException. Please have a look.

Comment: Check Button Object is Properly initialize with Right ID

Answer (score 1):

In your question you are not defining return statement, before use `findViewbyId` just use parameter of return statement.

```
 View abc = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activitys, container,false);  
 btn1 = (Button) abc.findViewById(R.id.btns);  
 return abc;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_laundry, container, false);

btn_service = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_service);

return V;

}
```

Comment: Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue. Please edit it to include information **why** this code dump solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Fragment you have initialize Fragment xml using LayoutInflater in onCreateView :

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_laundry, container,false);
```

After get xml reference using LayoutInflater try initialize Fragment xml all child views :

```
btn_service = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_service);
btn_service.setOnClickListener(this);
```

return Fragment xml reference to onCreateView at last statement :

```
return view;
```

**Note :** In your code you directly return Fragment xml before initialize Button so alwasys try to return Fragment xml reference at last statement of onCreateView().

Answer (score 0):

make the following changes...

View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_laundry, container,false);

now previx findViewById by myView.findViewById.

This should do the trick.